# Having issues installing OneDrive for Business unattended on client computers

Tags: onedrive

My company is planning to deploy Microsoft OneDrive for Business as a storage solution for enterprise customers and this of course needs to be a silent installation. I have looked at numerous forums regarding this issue and the answer seems quite simple, but yet even after I follow the directions and create the custom xml file I want to use and download the content (without any errors)from Microsoft and i use the setup /configure command I am never able to get this software to install successfully. I always get the following Office couldn't install. I can only assume ?I am doing something wrong or I am extremely unlucky. I on a time restraint for this too..so frustrating.

By the way this is the link I was using: http://sharepointfarmer.com/onedrive-for-business-app-silent-install/#comment-7766.

This is the error I get the same generic MS type error as always:

[image]

here is my xml file its pretty simple:

```
<Configuration> 
  <Add SourcePath="\\sscbplndsk01\packages\InTesting\Microsoft\OneDrive For Business\ODB Configuration\" OfficeClientEdition="32"> 
   <Product ID="GrooveRetail" > 
     <Language ID="en-us" />      
   </Product> 
  </Add> 
</Configuration>
```

Comment: This is my code I don't know why it was not included....            <Configuration> 
<Add SourcePath="\\sscbplndsk01\packages\InTesting\Microsoft\OneDrive For Business\ODB Configuration\" OfficeClientEdition="32"> 
<Product ID="GrooveRetail" > 
<Language ID="en-us" />      
</Product> 
</Add> 
</Configuration>

Comment: Hi Charlie84, I've fixed your XML in your question on your behalf. Please us ethe formatting tools of the editor to specify things like code blocks (`{}`), as this will help preserve formatting and deal with special characters properly.

Comment: Can you access the SourcePath (via Explorer for example) as the user you're running the silent install as?

Comment: I am able to manually install by running the EXE Setup.x86.en-us_GrooveRetail_3V9N8-W93CC-FQPB8-Y9WVF-TVGJ3_TX_PR_.exe this, but when i try to run the command even locally setup /configure config.xml  i get the error i supplied in the image.

Comment: Have you read the install logs it should create in %temp%?

Comment: I looked under both the user's temp directory and windows and i am not seeing any logs for it...i checked there too, because the article informed me to. also I just checked again.

Answer (score 0):

You should run [Office 2013 uninstaller](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Uninstall-Office-2016-Office-2013-or-Office-365-from-a-Windows-computer-9dd49b83-264a-477a-8fcc-2fdf5dbf61d8), then redownload the installer and add the following line to the end of final configuration.xml:

```
<Display Level="None" AcceptEULA="TRUE" />
</Configuration>
```

Also it might be useful to detect if OneDrive already installed before running setup.exe. Here is sample PowerShell script:

```
If ([IntPtr]::Size -eq 4) {
    # x86
    $Path = 'HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall'
}
Else {
    # x64
    $Path = 'HKLM:\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall'
}

$Office2013 = "$Path\OFFICE15*"
$Office365 = "HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\O365ProPlusRetail*"
$OneDrive = "HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\Groove*"
$SetupDir = "<UNC path to OneDrive installation directory>"


If (!(Test-Path $Office2013) -and !(Test-Path $Office365) -and !(Test-Path $OneDrive)) {
    Start-Process $SetupDir\setup.exe -ArgumentList "/configure $SetupDir\configuration.xml"
}
Else {
    # Echo "Already installed!"
}
```